# Is it possible to block an IP address on smartphone?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, android, html

Is it possible to block a website/ IP address in a smartphone by way of an app that people can download? I want to sell an app that blocks certain websites from being able to pull up on your phone.

Answer (score 3):

There is not really any such option in the SDK. You won't be able to do it in an app. You can only do it if you plan to distribute your own android ROM (You probably don't).

What you CAN do however is to sell a configurable proxy service and let people to connect toy your service by setting up your server as a proxy. This is also not such a trivial task by itself.

There is a dedicated blog to a android proxy settings:
http://android-proxy.blogspot.com/

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to create an adblocking app?
There's already one, but like Variant said, it uses proxies.

http://www.androlib.com/android.application.ub0r-android-adblock-zmmF.aspx